# rails datetime field in edit form says UTC

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a datetime field and the value is stored in mysql like this:

```
2014-08-26 16:00:00
```

When user selects datetime, they select it from a jquery datetime popup. And its inserted into text field and sent to the server at which point it is parsed like this:

```
def date_start=(s)
  datetime = parse_datetime s
  write_attribute :date_start, datetime
end

def parse_datetime(s)
  DateTime.strptime(s,'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
end
```

And then inserted into the database. Now when the user edits the form, the datetime is displayed in the text field, but it is displayed like this:

```
2014-08-26 16:00:00 UTC
```

Why does it say UTC there (the record is retrieved and stored local time) and how can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

It's considered good practice to store timestamps in your database as UTC time, regardless of which timezone they were originally (so they can be accurately compared and prevent messes that usually arise when things aren't consistent).

Active Record takes care of this by doing the conversion automatically. That means that when a user selects a datetime, you have to ensure it's given the right timezone in Rails/Ruby when it is inputted, using [`Time.use_zone()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-use_zone) or something similar. And similarly when displaying it after retrieving from the database. You'll need some way to retrieve the user's local timezone (Javascript or a manually selected profile option).

As an aside, if you want to set the default timezone for your application to something other than UTC, then you can change the `config.time_zone` option in `application.rb`. Note that the database will still store things in UTC, it just allows you to set a sensible default timezone for datetime input and output (i.e. a default timezone for Active Record to convert to/from). It won't help with individual user datetimes though, unless all your users reside in the same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't override writer at all. Rails shoudl handle it properly.
 In form show datetime like this:

```
 f.text_field :date_start, (f.object.date_start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p') if f.object.date_start ) ...
```

or make a method

```
def form_date_start
  date_start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p') if date_start
end
```

and in form

```
f.text_field :date_start, f.object.form_date_start
```